# How to write data to a specific line number in a file Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file

Title: Write data to a specific line number in a file

Here is my sample file:

```
public class MyC{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("My method has been accessed");
        Syst.out.println("hi");
        String l;
        nt x=0;
    }
}
```

What is my objective?

I want to go to the line 5 and correct the string Syst.out.println("hi"); to System.out.println("hi");
Till now I have been able to access the line having the error and had the string saved in a variable and replaced the error.

Here is what I achieved till now:

```
import java.io.*;
public class NewReplaceLine {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\workspace\\Compilers\\testfile.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            try {
                br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
        String lineIWant = br.readLine();
        String newtext = lineIWant.replace("Syst", "System");
        System.out.println(newtext);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

What I'm not being able to do is to rewrite the string I corrected to the line number 5 to the file back.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: The program goes to line 5 where the error occurs and replaces the string Syst by System and outputs it on the console. What i dont know is how to rewrite string back la to original position in
line number 5.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write to a second temporary file since you're still reading from the first one.  Once the replacement is complete and the file is completely written out, delete the first file and rename the second.

Edit:

Per your comment, if you want to make multiple or more complex changes to the file contents, you could break the task down into the following steps:

- Use FileInputStream to read the original file's contents as an input stream,
- Instead of wrapping the input stream in a BufferedReader, read the contents of the input stream and write them to a ByteArrayOutputStream ( a file that acts like an output stream but keeps the contents in memory as a byte array)
- Construct a new string using the byte array as a constructor argument
- Now you have a string in memory that contains the entire contents of the original file
- Once you've made your changes to that string, write it out to a second file using FileWriter
- use the File class to delete your original file and again to rename your output file

Comment: Can you provide me a sample code.Am completely stuck with this.Thanks about if i had to replace string in several lines then how to write to their respective position in the file.

Comment: I tried but i just dont work.can you help

Heres the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199781/how-to-replace-several-strings-in-file-on-different-line-numbers-and-output-to-a

Answer (score 1):

(Unless some 3rd party library does that,) you cannot do that (not only in Java but in other languages as well).

You can read / write to a file sequentially or with random access, but random access works with bytes and not with lines (the FS does not know if your file contains text or binary data). And, if you find the right byte and overwrite there, if you add more bytes that were in the original line, you will be overwritting the new one.

The option I would use would be reading sequentially and copying to a new file (taking care of write the new line in the right position) and close both files. After that, overwrite the old file with the new file.

Comment: the FS works **byte by byte**. Some Java API classes encapsulate that to allow you to read line by line, though.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Gerken
What if the file has more errors lets say lines 2,4,5,6,7 he'll need to find a way to write each line in a sequential manner one after the other(after having dealt with the lines having the errors) to the newly created file?